# my icon disappears when using navbar-fixed with materialize

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

my icon disappears when using navbar-fixed with materialize, but if I not use fixed my icon exists

with navbar :

[image]

with navbar-fixed :

[image]

Comment: Pictures are no good to us, show us your code insted

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo ">MBS EFAKTUR</a>
            <ul class="right">
              <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
              <li><a href="badges.html"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i></a></li>
              <li><a href="collapsible.html"><i class="material-icons">refresh</i></a></li>
              <li><a href="mobile.html"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**strong text**

Comment: I am using side-nav fixed too,